# Jquery selector ( input:checkbox) not working in Dynamic Action after filter

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a page with multiple checkbox and I have stored IDs of checkbox with multiple select through Dynamic Action. It is working absolutely fine but when I apply filter and Region is refreshing where Apex Item checkbox I put then Jquery selector is not working through DA.
`$s('P11_ROW_PK',`
`$("[name='f01']:checked").map(function(){`
`return this.value;`
`}).get().join(",")`
`);`

To get this working I have to refresh entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure your on-click dynamic action event scope is 'Dynamic', not 'Static'.

This must be done for any events like this on regions where they content may be partially refreshed, like a classic/interactive report.

Comment: It's a common problem. This re-applies the event listener for the refreshed content.